# Aws batch: Do array jobs create separate resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

AWS batch documentation states that array jobs share common parameters like job definition, vCPUs and memory. Does it mean if I have an array job of 1000 and vCPU as 4, each child job will get 4 vCPU or total vCPU across all child jobs will be 4?

Answer (score 0):

The former. The job definition defines the amount of resources for a given job. The array job then points to the job definition to state "this is what is required for each of the individual jobs in the array"

In your example, the each job gets 4 vCPU. Your compute environment will probably have some max number of vCPU. If that max is 8, then only 2 individual jobs run at the same time and the other 998 wait in the queue until resources are free.